# Duvida Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google, firebase-cloud-functions

O Cloud Function é como um servidor para NodeJS ?

Posso importar qualquer package do NPM e usar seu recurso, que vai funcionar normalmente no Cloud Functions?
Ou ele só trabalha com os recursos do google?

Tentei fazer um request em uma API de cep.
Porém o cloud functions não funcionou, mas no servidor local funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o [Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/firebase-cloud-functions-f6ed3787fa8d) executa código NodeJS. E pode importar qualquer package npm.

Mas o que acontece é que no plano Spark (gratuito) do Firebase, você só pode aceder aos serviços da Google. Se você quiser utilizar outras APIs, terá de fazer upgrade para um dos [planos pagos](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=pt-br).